# Is there a faster method for multiplying very large integers or storing them in many caches/variables instead of one to improve performance?

Tags: python

```
def exponentiation(base,n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    if n % 2 == 0:
     return exponentiation(base*base, n/2)
    else:
        return base * exponentiation(base * base, (n-1)/2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(len(str(exponentiation(2, 66666666))))
```

For very large integers, the computer becomes quite sluggish at finding the product of numbers; And I know that 1 Gigabyte of RAM can store atleast 2^8000000000 digits, but this program slows down far before this limit is reached.

I wished to use Exponentiation by squaring in order to improve the rate at which the program did the multiplications, but yet it seems as though there is a problem with the program storing such large integers.

Comment: If what you want to know is the number of digits in 2^66666666, I think there might be better algorithms than actually computing 2^66666666.

Comment: NOTHING can store that many *digits* as you claim. A GB has 8_000_000_000 bits, therefore it could store that many binary digits, and those could represent 2^800000000 different numbers but you can store exactly one of them.

Comment: Add some printing to your code to see where it starts getting stuck and for how long. Getting the string representation is most likely not a good idea since that string has more than 20 MILLION characters.

Comment: In your example code, most of the time is being taken up by converting the answer to a string. Also, just using the built-in `**` operator on integers yields the correct answer more quickly than your implementation, so you may want to stick with the default implementation on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the built-in `**` operator for this. It works significantly faster.

```py
big_number_a = 2 ** 66666666
big_number_b = exponentiation(2, 66666666)
big_number_a == big_number_b  # True
```

Also, don't try converting such a huge number to a decimal string with `str` unless you really have to. That part is **super slow**.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a faster way:

```py
exponentiation = pow
```

This is about twice as fast as your method, and it works for non-integers as well.

The exponentiation time in your code is negligible, though. Most of its time is spent converting the integers to strings. If you want the number of digits an integer has, use `int(math.log10(n)) + 1` instead.